# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 at Connection.openUri

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-web-server

I am getting error in my code that [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
Mongodb is running in my pc.

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const product = require("./routes/ProductRoutes");

app.use("/api/v2", product);

module.exports = app;
```

server.js

```
const app = require("./app");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const connectDatabase = require("./db/Database");

dotenv.config({
  path: "backend/config/.env",
});

connectDatabase();

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on https://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

database.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDatabase = () => {
  mongoose
    .connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(`mongodb is connected with server: ${data.connection.host}`);
    });
};

module.exports = connectDatabase;
```

.env

```
  PORT = 4000 
  DB_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce"
```

Mongodb is running in my pc.

Comment: Please edit your post, and provide the error's stack.

Comment: Please remove "mongoose-web-server" tag from this question.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `mongod` ipv6 support via commandline option [`--ipv6`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/#std-option-mongod.--ipv6) or configuration file option [`net.ipv6`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.ipv6)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DB_URL = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ecommerce"
```

instead of

```
DB_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce"
```

source:

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1-27017/123421/2

If no works provide mongoose, mongo and node version.

Answer (score -1):

try using this instead.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/ecommerce')
```